# Using jquery animate to highlight div on load

Tags: events, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery

I have a simple notification system. I want to use jquery to highlight the div onload by changing the background color and go back to normal after 500ms just a flash. Similar to when we answer questions on Stackoverflow. Simple enough to grab attention.

```
<div id="flash">Notification</div> 

 $(function() {
    $( "#flash" ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
     }, 1000 );
 });
```

It does not work as expected. It does not switch back to #ffffff.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI has a specific effect for this called [highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight). The issues of using `animate` on properties like `background-color` are described [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All
>   animated properties should be animated
>   to a single numeric value, except as
>   noted below; most properties that are
>   non-numeric cannot be animated using
>   basic jQuery functionality. (For
>   example, width, height, or left can be
>   animated but **background-color cannot
>   be**.) Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise
>   specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

**Edit** if you really don't want to go with the jQuery UI option, you could simulate a similar effect by wrapping the `background-color` into its own element and hiding that out.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/x2jrU/